# Count meta_keys (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a simple way to **count** how often a **meta_key exists in the database** like wordpress do with:

```
$n_post = wp_count_posts();
```

Anybody can help?

Comment: OK, I take a look ...

Answer (score 0):

Check last rows in a table which are associated with specific user/post, Take that ID and count meta_keys on the bases of that ID, Hope it will return all the meta_keys...